# SHA1PRNG SecureRandom behavior is different after seeding on java11

Tags: java, security, random, cryptography, sha

I am using `java.security.SecureRandom` with `"SHA1PRNG"` angorithm to generate encryption keys. This is a historical code used to encrypt lesser important data. Nevertheless when we've switched from **java8** to **java11**, our code stopped working. Here's the test case made to reproduce the situation:

```
@Test
void srEncryptionSeedTest() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
{
    final long versionSalt = 1850498708034063014L;
    final long customSalt  = -919666267416765972L;

    final SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
    sr.setSeed(versionSalt);
    final long l1 = sr.nextLong();
    final long l2 = sr.nextLong();

    sr.setSeed(customSalt);
    final long k1 = sr.nextLong();
    final long k2 = sr.nextLong();

    // check l1 and l2
    Assert.assertEquals(l1, 6338935000439666355L);
    Assert.assertEquals(l2, -7355545655857008441L);

    // Seeding
    // check k1 and k2
    Assert.assertEquals(k1, -2226559466996804670L); // 
    Assert.assertEquals(k2, -3123855249705841778L);
}
```

This works fine on java11, but on java8 we have `k1=-4273821888324981770` and `k2=3053251164341917236`, so the test fails. As you can see, the test starts failing after setting exactly the same seed after producing the same amount of same random numbers, so I suspect that the state of the RNG is different, but debugging wasn't helped me (I can not understand *why* it's different). This can be easily reproduced on any operation system.

**Some facts about the Java8 JVM:**

```
java.vendor -> Oracle Corporation // same goes on OpenJDK builds
java.version -> 1.8.0_202-ea // same goes on 1.8.0_181
java.vm.info -> mixed mode
java.specification.version -> 1.8
java.runtime.name -> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
```

**Some facts about the Java11 JVM:**

```
java.vendor -> AdoptOpenJDK
java.version -> 11.0.3
java.vm.info -> mixed mode
java.specification.version -> 11
java.runtime.name -> OpenJDK Runtime Environment
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `SecureRandom` never has claimed to generate the same values across runtimes.  Neither does the `"SHA1PRNG"` as the algorithm has even not been written down - it seems code only, and there have been implementation differences in the Java SE, other vendors runtimes and between Java and Android.

Comment: Thank you @MaartenBodewes! I'll double check it on Android and improve my question. Bonus question: is there any reliable RNG in Java that can satisfy my requirements?

Comment: I'll have to check, but [*this one*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/273) seems the best fit - I'll leave you with a bit of a quest to find the name for it. They check against test vectors and those vectors *should* have results for when the seed is updated. So in that case the only issue could be the translation between the calls by NIST and a Java API.

Comment: If you want to generate a cryptographic key use a password based key derivation function like PBKDF2 or if you need salting use a HMAC-SHA256 with the salt as key but NEVER EVER MISUSE A PRNG!!!

Comment: Thank you @Robert, i'd take it into account developing the next project, but overall this isn't my code and unfortunately it has to decrypt some already encrypted data (the initial purpose was to make a JSON config harder to modify to the user), so I can't change the approach right now (I wish I could, really).

I think I found the EXACT reason why the behavior is different, I'd better double check it and answer my own question.

Comment: @Netherwire If you have to stick with the current version copy the code of the SecureRandom you need and include it in your project. This is the only way to make it run on all platforms identical and independent of the current SecureRandom implementation the Java runtime provides.

Comment: @Robert I'd like to do it, but unfortunately it relies on many package-private code: [have a look](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/security/provider/SecureRandom.java)

Comment: @Netherwire The link points to the OpenJDK11 version which is the version that does not work. Anyway you don't need a full SecureRandom implementation just strip the code down until you get something working. Luckily you have the unit tests to test if everything works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[DISCLAIMER]:*** **Don't do it** (unless you want backwards compatibility). You should implement  your solutions based on reliable RNG if you want predictability, so did I. But unfortunately we had to support older file version's format, also these files does not contain any sensitive or personal data, but we didn't wanted users to alter this data since this is stored in the text-like format and thus easily could be altered.

I didn't implemented my own "SHA1PRNG", because it's too hard (mentioned in comments). Instead I hacked the newer PRNG version to behave exactly as the older one. The reason is the fact that since java9 OpenJDK creators decided to make the newer version of the `secureRandomSpi` to reset the value of the `remCount` integer field each time `SecureRandom.`[setSeed()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html#setSeed(long)) is called, which the older version did not.

If you want to implement this hack, first thing you have to do is to check whether the `SecureRandom` instance is truly a SUN's "SHA1PRNG" by calling `"SUN".equals(secureRandom.getProvider().getName()) && "SHA1PRNG".equals(secureRandom.getAlgorithm());` and then get it's SPI via reflection and save the value of its `remCount` field. Then you may call `setSeed()` and then install the saved value back to the `remCount` field. I don't want to post this obscure code here but you've got the idea. Thank you.

Comment: Beware that the algorithm may still change, although this is likely less of a problem now, since there are better DRBG's available.